# I can not update database in CodeIgniter 4 , model's update() function doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

how are you?
I have a problem with Mysql DB update using CI 4.x model update function.

```
$outletUpdateModel->where('id',$data['id'])->set($temp)->update()
```

There is no error with code. but I can not see any update on db.

Thank you for your time.

I used save() instead of update()

Comment: Perhaps the where clause does not match any existing rows.

Comment: Check the return value of `$outletUpdateModel->where('id',$data['id'])->set($temp)->getCompiledUpdate()` to see if it produces a valid sql statement. Then run this statement directly on the db to see if there are rows affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be obvious, but make sure you have all the fields you want to update in the `$allowedFields` property in the your model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class OutletUpdateModel extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'tableName';
    protected $primaryKey = 'primaryKey';

    protected $allowedFields = ['field1', 'field2'];
```

Many times when I ran into situations when records wouldn't get stored or updated, it turned out that I had forgotten to add fields to the `$allowedFields` array in the model after making changes to the code or database.